# Merge 2 text files ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, merge

I want to merge 2 .txt files into one text file. Let's say I have 2 text files. First one contains 100 rows only "Try Again". Like this one in the picture:

[image]

And the second text file contains bunch of random codes:

[image]

I want to merge these 2 text files, like this one in the picture below:

[image]

I have **one week** and I have not figured it out yet.

Comment: Can't you just read both files consequently and merge your lines and write it to the third file?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin , this is what I want. But I have not figured it out.

Comment: You can check this reference for reading the file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx and this for writing to files: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

Comment: What? 5 lines from file 1 followed by 1 line from file 2? Is that the deal?

Comment: @itsme86 , yes. this is the deal. :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I edit the code via Jim, he warned me and now it's working.
First you need to read both files and store all lines to string array. Then loop them like down bellow. Every fifth item you need to check and write from second file.
PS: I did not try the code but prob it will work without an error.

```
string[] first = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("path of first txt file");
string[] second = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("path of second txt file");

var sb = new StringBuilder();


var k = 0;
        var m = 0;
        for (int i = m; i < second.Length; i++)
        {
            m = i + 1;

            for (int j = k; j < first.Length; j++)
            {
                k = j + 1;

                if (j != 0 && j % 4 == 0)
                {
                    sb.Append(second[i] + "\n");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(first[j] + "\n");
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }


// create new txt file
var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("path of third txt file");
file.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Are you sure this is going to work right? Seems like it's going to output way too much stuff. That is, it will output all of `second` for each line of `first`. Perhaps you meant that `continue` to be a `break`? But that wouldn't work, either. I think you took the wrong approach. This problem cannot be solved by a simple nested loop structure like what you have.

Comment: Thanks Jim to correct me, I edit the code. I tested and worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just open both files and, in a loop, read four lines from the first and one line from the second. Output each line as it's read.

```
using (var outputFile = File.CreateText("OutputFile.txt"))
{
    using (var input1 = File.OpenText("TryAgain.txt"))
    using (var input2 = File.OpenText("File2.txt"))
    {
        while (!input1.EndOfStream  && !input2.EndOfStream))
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 4 && !input1.EndOfStream; ++i))
            {
                var s1 = input1.ReadLine();
                outputFile.WriteLine(s1);
            }
            if (i != 4) break; // end of first file
            // now read one line from the other file, and output it
            var s2 = input2.ReadLine();
            outputFile.WriteLine(s2);
        }
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of not having to read both files into memory all at once, and you don't have to build the entire output in memory. Each line is output immediately after it's written.